# How to get the names of all open buffers?

Tags: command-line, external-command, multiple-files

I can use `%` to get the name of the focused window for commands. How can I get a space-separated list of **all** buffers for use in a command?

For example, I would like to call

```
:!cat [all]
```

where `[all]` is something that evaluates to what I want.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Vi/Vim SE. Either `:args` or `:buffers`/`:ls` depending on what value  you have for `:set hidden?` :) Less cryptically, do you navigate files mostly with `:next`/`:prev` or other means?

Comment: I use `:e` having `:set hidden`. I hope my edit clarifies what I mean, thank you.

Comment: for the argument list, have a look at `:h :_##`

Comment: `where [all] is something that evaluates` Note that the whole line after `!` is simply passed to the shell. You have either to use `execute`, or pass the value inside an environment variable (so shell can expand it).

Comment: @Matt Not sure I get what you're saying. I would say `%` evaluates to something, or maybe "expands" is the better word.

Comment: @AugustJanse It's a "special" (`:h cmdline-special`). Yes, the specials get _expanded_ as a step separate from normal evaluation. So they are pretty much restricted. Therefore, you'll have to use `:execute` very often (that's a sort of "eval operator" for Vim).  Another possible alternative is the expression register (`<C-R>=`), but an interactive input is not always convenient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose by "open files" you mean active buffers (see `:h windows-intro`). That could be achieved with the command `:ls a` (use `h`-flag to get hidden buffers if needed).

To pack it into a function you could use a redirection or a dedicated `getbufinfo()` interface. For example

```
function! GetActiveBuffers()
    let l:blist = getbufinfo({'bufloaded': 1, 'buflisted': 1})
    let l:result = []
    for l:item in l:blist
        "skip unnamed buffers; also skip hidden buffers?
        if empty(l:item.name) || l:item.hidden
            continue
        endif
        call add(l:result, shellescape(l:item.name))
    endfor
    return l:result
endfunction

" the result is a list
" use join() when a single string is needed
":exec '!cat' join(GetActiveBuffers())
```

Comment: instead of parsing the output of `:ls`, you can use the `getbufinfo()` function

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thank you. I knew there must be something like this...

Comment: With `:!cat $myargs` you're likely to run into escaping issues (it's actually probably going to ruin your use of `shellescape()`!) Much better is `:execute '!cat' join(GetActiveBuffers())`, which would assemble the command-line in Vim, rather than use a variable expansion in the spawned shell. (Hint: test it with files containing spaces and special characters and you'll see the difference.)

Comment: @filbranden Yes, you're right. It turns out that it's quite hard to escape the things in the right way. `exec` looks easier to deal with.